# How to make an SSRS subscription with no delivery methods

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, report

im using SSRS reporting service,
on the `Delivered by` i have the `E-Mail` and `window file share` options,
I want the reports run every hour but i dont want to get a mail or any other delivery.
is it possible?
how can i do it?
Thanks..

Comment: Why do you want generate a report without delivering it? Do you want to [cache](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155927.aspx) it?

Comment: yes. how do i do it?

Answer (score 1):

You can configure the [cache](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155927.aspx) for a report in the [Cache Refresh](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee636367.aspx) options in the Report Manager

---

From MSDN:

1. Open Report Manager, and locate the report or shared dataset for which you want to configure cache refresh plan properties.
2. Hover over the report or shared dataset, and click the drop-down arrow.
3. In the drop-down list, click Manage. The General properties page opens.
4. Click the Cache Refresh Plan tab.
5. To create a new cache plan, click New Cache Refresh Plan.

> **Note**
>   You must enable and start the SQL Server Agent service to create a cache refresh plan.

6. To create a copy of a cache plan and then customize it, click New from Existing